Vue 3 Type Declarations Docs
Where can I find the documentation for Vue 3 types such as HTMLAttributes or Component, been looking around in the documentation even using the search.
The only way to read them is by going to runtime-dom.d or runtime-core.d and reading the types.

This is how TS types for a particular lib are commonly learned, from d.ts files. Everything that the official docs are able to provide is available in TS chapter

The types HTMLAttributes and Component are not documented on the Vue.js website. Instead, they are defined only in the files runtime-dom.d.ts and runtime-core.d.ts, so the only way to read them is by directly checking those files.

If you mean if you can type a component Ref yes you can. Since vue 3.5 you can type a component template ref :100 https://vuejs.org/guide/typescript/composition-api.html#typing-component-template-refs
For other types. When you search for something there is always a section for typing.
For a general typescript overview https://vuejs.org/guide/typescript/overview.html
